# Help on a quick proofs regarding open sets and the 'int' of a set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B\subset $$ \mathbb  R$. Let A be an open subset of B. Show that $A\subset int(B)$

I know that A is an open set if and only if the $int(A) = A$, but what does it mean to be an open subset of B? does that mean that $int(A) = B$

Comment: Not in the least!  The question is that $B$ can doesn't have to be an open set and can have many points that are not interior points. But you need to prove that if $A$ is open then $A$ doesn't contain *any* of those points. .... In other words you have to prove $A$ contains only *interior* point of $B$ and *can't* contain any other points of $B$.  A third way of putting this is that an interior point of $A$ is also an interior point of $B$.

Comment: Im confused what it means when "A an open subset of B", could I have some insight?

Comment: It means that $A$ is open, and it is a subset of $B$

Comment: It means nothing more or less than $A$ is a subset that happens to be open.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $A$ is open iff $\text{int}(A)=A$, where $\text{int}(A)$ is the set of all interior points of $A$. Let $x\in A$. Since $x$ is an interior point of $A,\exists a,b\in A$ such that $x\in(a,b)\subset A$. Now, since $A$ is a subset of $B$, every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$. This means $x\in B, (a,b)\subset B$.

$\therefore \forall x\in A, \exists a,b\in B$ such that $x\in(a,b)\subset B$, or that $x$ is an interior point of $B$, and $A\subseteq \text{int}(B)$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I can see the logic now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To be an open subset of $B$ is simply to be a subset of $B$ and an open set. Recall that the definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is that for every $x \in A$ there exists some $r$ such that $\{y \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ |y-x| < r \} \subset A$, that is, there will always be enough "room" in the set to fit in an interval of positive length.

To prove that $A \subset \text{int}(B)$, you can try the familiar ways of proving set inclusions, take $x \in A$ arbitrarily, and prove from the properties of $A$ that you know, that it must also be in $\text{int}(B)$. Ok so now that we have our strategy, we see that if $x \in A$ then by the definition of $A$ being open, there is some $r > 0$ such that the set $B_1(x ; r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ |y-x| < r \} \subset A \subset B$ (here I'm using the notiaton $B_1$ for a "ball"). But since we know that $A$ is a subset of $B$, $B_1(x;r) \subset B$ and so we also have that $x \in B$ (since $x \in A$). By definition of an interior of a set, it is those points such that there exists some open ball centered at that point such that it is contained in that set, by definiton, $x$ satisfies this since $B_1(x;r) \subset B$ and so $x \in \text{int}(B)$. Therefore $A \subset \text{int}(B)$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. What do you mean by open ball? I have never heard that before.

Comment: The "ball" of radius $r$ centered $x$ is simply the set $\{y \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ |y-x| < r \}$ the use of the term makes more sense in higher dimensions (imagine how this might look in the plane, like a circle in fact). But I am simply using that as shorthand for that set I just described

Comment: Might be a bit above the level we are doing in my class, but thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

No, it just means that $A$ is a subset of $B$, and $A$ is open.

Proof of the original problem: Since $A$ is open, for all $p\in A$, there exists a ball $B(p)$ whose center is $p$, such that $B(p)\subset A \subset B$, which indicates that $p\in \mathrm{int}(B)$. Thus $A\subset\mathrm{int}(B)$.

Comment: What do you mean by ball whose center is p? I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: 'Ball' is used to denote a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following. What do you mean by neighborhood of x?

Comment: The $\delta$-neighbourhood of $x$ is defined as the interval $N_{\delta}(x):=\{y: y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\}=\{y: |x-y|<\delta\}$. It is basically an open interval containing points close to $x$

Comment: @PabloTores What is the definition of open sets that you have been taught?

Comment: A set $X$ is open if and only if $int(X) = X$

Comment: @PabloTores Then what is the definition of int(X) you have been taught?

Comment: X is an interior point of A if and only if there exists $(a,b)$ in A such that X is in $(a,b)$.

Comment: It seems that this definition only works with the one-dimension $\mathbb R$. In the general case, we say $B(p)$ is a ball of center p and radius r to indicate $B(p) = \{x\mid |x-p| < r\}$. In $\mathbb R$, the ball is just a neighborhood like @Schubham Johri said.